# how can I efficiently pad a RGB pixel to make it the center pixel of a resulting image using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have an image consisting of 100 pixels. for each pixel, I want to pad it with zeros (if on the edge) so that it's in the center, concatenate with neighboring pixels and generate a new 10x10 image. Thus I want to generate 100 images from the original image by sliding through each pixel along the row. e.g. for pixel[0,0], I want to add 4 zero columns on right, 4 zero rows on top, neighboring 5 column pixels on right and neighboring 5 row pixels on the bottom.

Can someone guide me on how this is done for a RGB image with numpy?

```
def unpickle_im(file, type):
import Image
im1 = Image.open(file)
im1p = np.asarray(im1, dtype=type)
return im1p

imc2p = unpickle_im('tmp/RGB-00000.png', 'float32')
##imc2p.shape = (10,10,3)

padded = np.zeros(10,10,3) ##Create a padded image filled with zeros
for i in xrange(im2cp.shape[0]):
for j in xrange(im2cp.shape[1]):
    if(i < 5  or j < 5) :
        new_im2cp = np.pad(im2cp[i:5, j:5], ((4-i,4-j),(0,0)))
    else:
        new_im2cp = np.pad(im2cp[i-4:i+5, j-4:j+5])
```

edit: adding the correct snippet after @dabhaid's post:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np, time

im_array = np.random.rand(10,10,3)
pad = 4
padded_array  = np.pad(im_array, ((pad,pad+1),(pad,pad+1),(0,0)), 'constant')
for i in xrange(im_array.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(im_array.shape[1] ):
       temp_im = padded_array[i:i+10, j:j+10]
       # print temp_im.shape
       if i == 0 and j == 0:
        new_im = temp_im[np.newaxis,...]
       else:
        new_im = np.vstack([new_im, temp_im[np.newaxis,...]])
```

Comment: Do you just want to make a 10x10 image of each pixel?

Comment: instead of conditionally padding the sub-images, how about padding the original image and then generating sub images from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np, time

im_array = np.random.rand(10,10,3)
pad = 4
padded_array  = np.pad(im_array, ((pad,pad+1),(pad,pad+1),(0,0)), 'constant')
for i in xrange(im_array.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(im_array.shape[1] ):
       temp_im = padded_array[i:i+10, j:j+10]
       # print temp_im.shape
       if i == 0 and j == 0:
        new_im = temp_im[np.newaxis,...]
       else:
        new_im = np.vstack([new_im, temp_im[np.newaxis,...]])
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume you have an RGB image (rather than an RGBA). As per the comments, is this what you want?

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open('100.png')
im_array = np.array(image)
stack = np.array(100, 20, 20, 3) #100 of the padded arrays

for i in xrange(im_array.shape[0]):
    for j in xrange(im_array.shape[1]):
        padded = np.zeros((20,20,3))
        padded[9][9] = im_array[i][j]
        stack[i*j] = padded
```

It seems wasteful, memory-wise.

#### edit in response to question update

instead of padding the new images conditionally, pad the original image and then just copy sub-images out of it:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open('100.png')
im_array = np.array(image)
pad = 4 #pixels
padded_array = np.pad(im_array, ((pad,pad+1),(pad,pad+1),(0,0)), 'constant')
# pad 4 elements to the left, right, up and down, but leave the pixel values alone
# default value is zero
for i in xrange(im_array.shape[0] - (pad + pad+1)):
    for j in xrange(im_array.shape[0] - (pad + pad+1)):
        new_imarray = padded_array[i:i+9, j:j+9]
        # do what you need with the new image
```

Comment: I want to make each pixel the center pixel of the new image. So the pixels on the edge need to be padded with zeros so that I can still generate a 10x10 image. Also I want to save this data in a numpy array, e.g. vstack each of the resulting images- Thanks

Comment: How are you defining the center pixel of an even width (10x10) image? And on a higher level what are you trying to do?

Comment: i am planning to pad 9 columns on the left, 10 columns on the right, 9 rows on top and 10 rows on bottom

Comment: So to be clear: you want, for every pixel, to create a 20x20 narray of RGB values, with one non-zero value at [9][9]?

Comment: yes, that's correct. how do I concatenate np.zeros(array) to the pixels on the edge, whereas this is not required for the pixels in the middle. I also something on using stride function, still not clear about it (I got the hint by your usage of PIL)

Comment: this actually makes the `im_array[i][j]` the corner pixel. At the same time, we need to pad with zeros only if the pixels are on the edge, e.g. `padded[i+9][j+9] = im_array[i][j]`

Comment: it should have been `padded[9][9]` that was always set - I've fixed that, but your last comment makes me think you just want to pad the original array (so you can run a 10x10 convolution over it).